# Не обновляется схема БД, несмотря на ddl-auto=update

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Имеются сущности вида

```
package com.foo.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "transport_list")
public class TransportList {

    @Id
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(name = "transport_list_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "closed")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Boolean closed;

}
```

Application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dfr-boot?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=lol
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Все прекрасно создается. Но как только я добавляю новое поле ( тип не имеет значения, результат тот же ) ничего не происходит

```
@Column(name = "foobar")
@Getter
@Setter
private String foobar;
```

В БД новое поле не создается. Хотя по логам якобы все гуд

```
[INFO] 2018-06-07 16:01:42.499 [restartedMain] LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
[DEBUG] 2018-06-07 16:01:42.669 [restartedMain] SQL - 

    alter table dfr-boot.transport_list 
       add column foobar varchar(255)
```

Если таблицу дропнуть - тогда все поля создаются как надо.

Comment: Данная проблема проявляется со spring boot версии 2.0. Если откатиться на 1.5.7 все работает как надо. Интересно как это исправить в версии 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема ( хотя на версии Spring boot 1.5.14 и так работает ) заключалась в наименовании БД. Имя было **dfr-boot**, после переименования в **dfr_boot** проблема решилась